# UIScrollView Subview Scaling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scaling

I'm attempting to scale a UIScrollView's subviews, based off of how far away they are from the center of the container. I think I'm close, but it isn't quite right. The views to the left of the center line are scaled a bit less than those to the right.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for( unsigned int i=0; i<[scrollView.subviews count]; i++ )
    {
        UIView *v = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        // not quite right here
        float scale = 1. - ( abs(scrollView.center.x - ( v.center.x - scrollView.contentOffset.x ) ) / scrollView.contentSize.width/2 );

        v.alpha = scale;

        v.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        v.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(v.transform, scale, scale);

    }
}
```

If anyone has any thoughts, I'd greatly appreciate it, as it has been a long day fighting with this.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your scale calculation you can see there's something wrong in the first part of it. Imagine the following values:
scrollview center x = 10
scrollView contentOffset x = 30
v1 center x = 5
v2 center x = 15

v1 and v2 are mirrored (5 pixels to the left of the center and 5 to the right of the center), so they should return the same scale value.
If you do the calculation with your code, it returns 35 and 25, which means the calculation isn't right.

I'm not sure how do you want your scale to behave exactly but a suggestion would be:

```
float scale = 1. - ( (scrollView.contentOffset.x - abs( v.center.x - scrollView.center.x ) ) / scrollView.contentSize.width/2 );
```

Edit:
try this one:

```
float scale = 1. - (abs( v.center.x - scrollView.center.x ) ) / scrollView.contentSize.width/2 );
```

There are many ways of doing your calculation. My point is that you should make sure that your operations are giving you the expected results with fake values, and yours is not. Your dividend is giving wrong results.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be quite what I'm going for. I'd like the view in the "center" (it is a paged scrollview, as wide as a single page, not clipping subviews) to be at scale = 1.;. I'd like the views to the left and the right to get scaled down as they get farther from the first. Something like (bad ascii): `_-|-_` where those are 5 views, the middle at scale 1, the next at like .7, then .5, if that makes sense.

Comment: Edited my answer with another example

Comment: Still not working, now it decreases from the far left of the scrollview's content window, not the center outward on both sides.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't do more without access to the project. Try with different calculations until you get your desired result. My advise is to do it "on paper" first to be sure it makes sense. Once implemented, NSLog all the values to see how and why they are changing.